# How to run write adb command result on host system not an emulator from python script

Tags: python, adb

The following command works fine when I run it through Terminal.

```
adb -s 192.168.100.101:5555 shell tcpdump -nnvvettU -s 0 -i eth1 > dump.txt
```

But when I try to run it from python script it try to write on emulator which fails as follow:

```
#Python script:
cmd_str = "adb -s 192.168.100.101:5555 shell tcpdump -nnvvettU -s 0 -i eth1 > dump.txt"
cmd = cmd_str.split() 
call(cmd)

#Error:
/system/bin/sh: can't create dump.txt: Read-only file system
```

so how can I write the file on the host system not an emulator in python script?